# How to use Parcelable in AIDL

Tags: android, parcelable, aidl

I define a class which implements `Parcelable`, like this:

```
public class Book implements Parcelable
```

And I know I can use this class in AIDL file like this:

```
import com.okay.demo.aidl.bean.Book;
interface IBookManager {
   void addBook(in Book book);
}
```

But what I want to know is that can I just `Parcelable` in AIDL file suppose I don't know the implementation class? Can I just use `Parcelable` like this :

```
interface IBookManager {
   void addData(in Parcelable data);
}
```

I had tried replace `Book` with `Parcelable`, but it didn't work.

Or can not it do this in AIDL ?

Comment: no, you cannot use `Parcelable` interface here, it has to be a class implementing this interface

Comment: Of course, you can use Parcelable for IPC like that, just not with out-of-box AIDL tool. Have a look at this library I wrote: https://github.com/chdir/aidl2. It generates code, that uses Binder objects directly to pass  runtime-defined Parcelables, Serializables and even other IPC interfaces between processes.

Comment: @pskink: How did you figure out its not possible? Do you have any code/doc reference?

Comment: *"Do you have any code/doc reference?"* - @Yash maybe 4 years ago i would have remembered ... ;-)

Comment: hehe.. I ran into same issue today and wanted to have an authoritative answer either way. Its of course not compiling for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) says you should create an AIDL file for your class `Book`. Your `Book.aidl` should look like:

```
import com.okay.demo.aidl.bean.Book;

// Declare Rect so AIDL can find it and knows that it implements
// the parcelable protocol.
parcelable Book;
```

With this new file, you can now use `Book` in your AIDL file:

```
import com.okay.demo.aidl.bean.Book;

interface IBookManager {
   void addData(in Book book);
}
```